# Json Encode Multi dimension array format

Tags: php, json

im retrieving some data in my database table and than convert to json, but i need to create a array with this structire in my php loop

```
["postcode"=>"townName"...]
```

but instead is giving me

```
["postcode=>townName"...]
```

My code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM uk_postcodes";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    $dname_list = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {

        $dname_list[] = $row['postcode']."=>".$row['town'];
    }
    echo json_encode($dname_list);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that line:

```
$dname_list[] = $row['postcode']."=>".$row['town'];
```

You're creating a string with "=>" in the middle (see [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)). You should specify the key of the array to be the postcode field, and the value - town field. Just change that line to:

```
$dname_list[$row['postcode']] = $row['town'];
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php